# Woocommerce get order items of similar orders

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In a plugin I'm trying to not letting users placing similar orders with same billing information.
Imagine a user with John Doe billing first name and last name has placed an order which contains product1 and product2 and someone else tries to place same or similar order (for example containing product1,product2, product3) with same billing first name and last name while the previous order is still under processing.
So in order to avoid this behavior I'm trying to validate orders before placement.
If there are any running orders with same billing info I throw a Woocommerce error but I don't know how can I make sure if last orders contain similar items too!
Here is my code:

```
function check_for_duplicate_order($data)
{

        $data['billing_last_name'];
        $data['billing_first_name'];
        $data['billing_postcode'];
        $meta_query_args = array(
            'relation' => 'OR', // Optional, defaults to "AND"
            array(
                'key'     => '_billing_postcode',
                'value'   => '%' . $data['_billing_postcode'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => '_billing_phone',
                'value'   => '%' . $data['billing_phone'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'     => '_billing_first_name',
                    'value'   => $data['billing_first_name'],
                    'compare' => '='
                ),
                array(
                    'key'     => '_billing_last_name',
                    'value'   => $data['billing_last_name'],
                    'compare' => '='
                )
            )
        );
        $query_params = [
            'post_type' => 'shop_order',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'post_status' => array('wc-pending','wc-processing','wc-on-hold'),
            'meta_query' => $meta_query_args

        ];
        $cart_items_ids = [];
        global $woocommerce;
        $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
        foreach($items as $item => $values) {
            $cart_items_ids[] = $values['data']->get_id();
        }

    }
    add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'check_for_duplicate_order');
```

In above code I get current order billing info, then finding other active orders with same billing info but from this point I don't know How can get found orders items and see if in previous orders there are same items too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to match items in current cart with items in previous orders :

```
foreach ($billing_active_order_ids as $active_order_id){
    $order = wc_get_order( $active_order_id );
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $id => $order_item){

        if(in_array($order_item->get_product_id(),$cart_items_ids)){
            wc_add_notice($duplicate_order_message, 'error');
            return;
        }

    }
}
```